# Use of "entire" as an adverb or adjective

Tags: adverbs

> “ Gut Symmetries were persuasively interpreted and later incorporated **entire** by developing Christianity.”

In this book, author seems to use this word (instead of -ly). Why? Do you not use -ly words to modify nouns?

Comment: What book? When written?

Comment: You have actually left the noun out of the sentence.  *{some things} were ... later incorporated entire*, or is the noun in your title?

Comment: I assume this is what the ellipsis means, but I have no idea what "gut symmetries" are.

Comment: Huh, the theology books I've read have left out Gut Symmetries entirely.  I must be reading the wrong books.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The bigger fish swallowed the smaller fish entire.

The word **entire** there means "whole", not bitten into smaller bits.

I would understand it as an object complement not an adverb modifying **swallowed**.

Comment: Ahh. This makes some sense. Thank you, as usual, Tᴚoɯɐuo.

Answer (score 0):

Normally, adverbs do take an *-ly* form.

However, it used to be that other forms were more frequent in the past. They can sound odd, but it's not always wrong.

(A "classic" example is road signs that read **drive slow**.)

The use of **entire** as an adverb, rather than **entirely**, is one of those specific cases of a word that is still used in this way. It sounds "old fashioned" but it's still in use.

From Merriam-Webster's entry for [**entire**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/entire):

> **— entire** *adverb*

When using this word as an adverb, it only goes after a verb. (Regular adverbs can also go in front of verbs, as with *entirely incorporated*.)

Comment: I think you meant adverb in the last paragraph. Please check my edit. Also I'm not sure what you mean the the -ed form, as the two examples (slow and entire) don't end "-ed"

Comment: @JamesK Thanks! (I like to think that I normally make more sense than that . . .)